# Div is pushed down the page when filled with content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a webpage that has two boxes side by side, filled with content (text/images, etc.). This is part of my code

HTML:

```
<p><b>Text Here</b></p>

<div id="col1">
    test
</div>

<div id="col2">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#col1 {
    margin-right: 25px;
}

#col2 {
    margin-left: 25px;
}

#col1, #col2 {
    background: #ddd;
    display: inline-block; 
    height: 300px;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 443px;
}
```

I tried using `float: right` and `float: left` but then the margins for my footer would not work properly (Also the slideToggle effect I'm using wasn't as smooth). Here is a JSFiddle showing the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/srCjs/

Thanks!

Comment: instead of using `div` tag use `span` tag ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the default value of `vertical-align` for an `inline-block` element is `baseline` - you can change the display value to block or change the vertical-align value to `bottom` and the elements will line up like expected:

http://jsfiddle.net/srCjs/1/

```
#col1, #col2 {
background: #ddd;
display: inline-block; /* or change the display value */
height: 300px;
padding: 15px;
vertical-align: bottom;
width: 443px;
}
```